# How to add in-text references?

Tags: reference, citations

I tried to google, but I have not found solution for my question. I have references, e.g. `[1], [2],.. etc`. But directly in text, I want to add citation, [1] + chapter name, because I references a lot to one source, and I am just pointing to different chapters. How should it be done then? `[1, Chapter 1, Chapter name]`? or `[1] - Chapter 1, Chapter Name.`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are are you targeting ? Markdown ? Latex ?

Comment: no, just the style, how it should look like? I do not know what is a correct one, [1, chapter 1, chapter name] or [1]: chapter1, chapter name,....

Comment: just the rules how those types of citations should be done?